# Error while Including third party module in kivy app

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am trying to import some third party module like pygoogle in my app when i run app in computer using kivy it works fine but when i make apk using buildozer it crashes every time then i find that i have to go in python-for-android and run this command to include module ./distribute.sh -m "pil ffmpeg kivy" but i still get error that

```
root@kali:~# cd ~/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
root@kali:~/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android# ls
COPYING        dist           docs     README.rst  src
cythonizer.py  distribute.sh  LICENSE  recipes     tools
root@kali:~/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android# ./distribute.sh -m "pil ffmpeg kivy"
Check build dependencies for Kali
Avoid check build dependencies, unknow platform Kali
Check environment
No ANDROIDSDK environment set, abort
root@kali:~/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android#
```

I am using KAli Linux and please solve this someone ...it will be very helpfull to me

Answer (score 1):

Try pasting the pygoogle folder in your app's directory, at the same level as `main.py`. Also, from the error, it looks like you need to set the ANDROIDSDK environment variable. See the [docs](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.org/en/latest/prerequisites/).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and simply setting the ANDROIDSDK environment variable didn't sort it, but the following did.

Try the following and then run the `./distribute.sh -m "pil ffmpeg kivy"` command from the same terminal(as the environment vars will only have been set for that terminal and any child processes), or alternatively, add these lines to your `~/.bashrc` file for them to be permanent:

```
export ANDROIDSDK=/path/to/android-sdk
export ANDROIDNDK=/path/to/android-ndk
export ANDROIDNDKVER=rX
export ANDROIDAPI=X

# example
export ANDROIDSDK="/home/tito/code/android/android-sdk-linux_86"
export ANDROIDNDK="/home/tito/code/android/android-ndk-r7"
export ANDROIDNDKVER=r7
export ANDROIDAPI=14
```

Examples taken from [here](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.org/en/latest/prerequisites/). I recommend having a look.

Comment: It is giving me this error ...root@kali:~/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android# ./distribute.sh -m "pil ffmpeg kivy"
Check build dependencies for Kali
Avoid check build dependencies, unknow platform Kali
Check environment
SDK located at /usr/bin
NDK located at /usr/bin
NDK version is r7
API level set to 14
Check NDK location
Invalid NDK platform
Looking in /usr/bin/platforms/android-14/arch-arm
Using ANDROIDNDK=/usr/bin and ANDROIDAPI=14

Comment: and honestly i dont know what is path of sdk and ndk ...please someone can help me ???

Comment: You need to alter your bulldozer.Spec file appropriately.. Edit my answer soon as I get to a computer

Comment: i solved that but after installing pygoogle or any third party module it is not showing in my aviable modules but it shows in python-for-android/dist but still i can not import pygoogle or nmap module in my main file even after adding the nmap or pygoogle in requirments of buildozer.spec